# How to pause SpVoice immediately in WPF?

Tags: wpf, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I want to do Text-to-speech with many voices in many languages.

I tried `SpeechSynthesizer` (Ref: System.Speech) but it only allows 2 English voices. After installing 6 English voices from Microsoft site, I still cannot get any other voices.

I changed to `SpVoice` (Ref: Microsoft Speech Object Library). SpVoice can recognize 6 voices I just installed. The problem is when I call `spVoice.Pause()`, it always delay 0.5 second before it stops speaking completely. I also tried to set `AlertBoundary` for SpVoice but it didn't help.

SpeechSynthesizer can pause right away with `SpeakAsyncCancelAll` but only works with default voices.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,the `Pause` method pauses the voice at the nearest alert boundary and closes the output device, allowing it to be used by other voices.

`spVoice.Speak()` method can be called synchronously or asynchronously. When called synchronously, the method does not return until the text has been spoken; when called asynchronously, it returns immediately, and the voice speaks as a background process.

I hope you are calling `spVoice.Speak()` synchronously. Thats why you are getting this issue. So use asynchronous method instead of synchronous,your problem should be solved. Then `spVoice.Pause()` will pause immediately.

```
SpVoice spVoice = new SpVoice ();
spVoice.Speak ("Testing spVoice",SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
//......
spVoice.Pause();
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I used spVoice asynchronously. I don't think this is a solution.